# IIB Mq Output "Error converting character string" when Croatian š in Json body

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

If MQ output get a Json message with a Croatian š it will fail with error message "Error converting character string".
I tried setting codepage to 1208 don't seem to help.
The Croatian š  is part of UTF-8

Compute node only set the property  with out to MQ output

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE getTest_Compute
CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN 
      SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data .name                    =     ' š ' ;   

    RETURN TRUE;
    END;

 END MODULE;
```

Image of flow:

[image]

Full Errro message:

> ```
>                       Text:CHARACTER:JSON writing errors have occurred
>                       RecoverableException
>                               File:CHARACTER:C:\ci\product-build\WMB\src\CommonServices\ImbConverter.cpp
>                               Line:INTEGER:882
>                               Function:CHARACTER:ImbConverterCPP::fromUnicode
>                               Type:CHARACTER:
>                               Name:CHARACTER:
>                               Label:CHARACTER:
>                               Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
>                               Severity:INTEGER:3
>                               Number:INTEGER:2130
>                               Text:CHARACTER:Error converting character string
>                               Insert
>                                       Type:INTEGER:2
>                                       Text:CHARACTER:850
>                               Insert
>                                       Type:INTEGER:2
>                                       Text:CHARACTER:10
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You are using IBM code page 850 as the output character set. This does not support the character that you are trying to output.

You need to set the output character set to a Unicode encoding - UTF-8 is the normal choice. This should do the job:

```
SET OutputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId = 1208;
```

The above code has not been tested, but hopefully you get the idea anyway.